# <security:custom-authentication-provider /> means?

Tags: spring, gwt, spring-mvc, spring-security

i have a bean in xml like below

```
<bean id="theCustomAuthenticationProvider" class="test.custom.CustomAuthenticationProvider">
<security:custom-authentication-provider />
```

> **a**.may i know what does security:custom-authentication-provider means when i put it in my bean like above?

**b**. do i need to create

```
<bean id="authenticationManager" class="org.springframework.security.providers.ProviderManager"> ref to theCustomAuthenticationProvider
```

in the xml ?

**c**. if b. answer is yes,  alternatively, can i use ref of theCustomAuthenticationProviderinside   tag?

Answer (score 3):

The idea is that marking a bean:

```
<security:custom-authentication-provider />
```

Will registor the bean as a authentication provider with the `AuthenicationManager` provided by spring security. You don't need **b**.